# How can i make space station moving effect along the star skybox?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't see the skybox in the scene view only when running the game i see the skybox outside the spaceship.

What i want to do is moving slowly the space station so it will looks like it's moving around the star skybox. Since it's a skybox i guess i can't really make the space station moving around it, but at least making it moving beside it.

This is a screenshot before running the game in the scene view i tried to zoom out as i can from the space station so you can see there is no skybox, at least not viewable.

[image: Brg]

And this is after running the game and when looking from outside the window:

[image: Outw]

When the player will look at the window i want to give him a feeling the space stating is in a move.

Comment: Can the skybox or the window you see from it be made it change its location over time?  If not, placing  a texture over the window and moving its UVs slowly to give the effect of the earth rotating (or space station moving around the earth) could do the trick.  You could also slowly shift stars in the for background as well on a different layer for more realism.

Comment: Maybe this link could help https://answers.unity.com/questions/21515/how-do-i-make-a-moving-skybox.html